# Does Ajax connection disconnect at some point?

Tags: ajax, connection

My Co-worker told me that AJAX connection alive until a user closes his/her browser. As far as I know, ajax connection closes its connection when its request has completed. I tested it with Firebug and a HTTP monitoring tool, I noticed that AJAX connection closes itself.

Is he correct????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break down what AJAX is -- and XMLHttpRequest. It's a connection to a URI endpoint for some resource (image, text, whatever). Your browser closes the HTTP connection as soon as it's done.

Answer (score 3):

Ajax is just like any other request, when it completes the connection is closed. Your colleague is wrong.

Note : There are connection types that allow you to keep the connection open indefinitely

Answer (score 1):

Ajax connections closed after receiving data or if you close tab, then connections will force closed.

[Here](http://ajaxblog.com/archives/2009/01/26/life-cycle-of-ajax) described Ajax life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here, but this regards an issue I'm actually dealing with right now...

I have a web server running on a severely resource constrained platform (128k Flash, 48k RAM) so it can only handle one connection at a time. Further connections are not handled until the current one is closed.  Also, it does not force `Connection: close` on certain URLs because of a low latency requirement. In general, only one thing talks to the device at a time.

AJAX connections follow whatever rules the browser sets for other connections. In my case, I'm testing a web page that uses AJAX to read one of the keep-alive-allowed URLs once per second, and the browser *does not close the connection* until several seconds after the *window* is closed. As a result, other clients wait indefinitely.

So **don't assume that XHR connections are closed when complete.** They might not be; Firefox 21 sure isn't closing them.

My current problem is that I want to force my AJAX requests to close the socket on completion, and I'm using jQuery's `.ajaxSend()` pre-send hook to set the `Connection: close` header. The AJAX seems to be working, but when another client tries to connect, it gets "connection reset by peer", so I'm wondering if Firefox doesn't notice the "Connection: close" header on the XHR request and keeps its end of the socket open (until it times out after approximately three seconds) even after the server has closed its side.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery to make AJAX requests, some connections are maintained until the following AJAX call. This can become a real problem when the server holds streams open until the response's close event fires.